# How to handle calling convention when wrapping C-code in Cython?

Tags: c, cython, pdfium

I'm trying to interface PDFium with Cython and ran into these defines/signatures:

```c
#if defined(COMPONENT_BUILD)

#if defined(WIN32)
#if defined(FPDF_IMPLEMENTATION)
#define FPDF_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FPDF_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  // defined(FPDF_IMPLEMENTATION)
#else
#if defined(FPDF_IMPLEMENTATION)
#define FPDF_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
#define FPDF_EXPORT
#endif  // defined(FPDF_IMPLEMENTATION)
#endif  // defined(WIN32)
#else
#define FPDF_EXPORT
#endif  // defined(COMPONENT_BUILD)

#if defined(WIN32) && defined(FPDFSDK_EXPORTS)
#define FPDF_CALLCONV __stdcall
#else
#define FPDF_CALLCONV
#endif


FPDF_EXPORT void FPDF_CALLCONV
FPDF_InitLibraryWithConfig(const FPDF_LIBRARY_CONFIG* config);
```

I'm just used to the simple function declaration with

```c
return_type function_name();
```

How to wrap signatures containing calling conventions in Cython?

Comment: Look in the pdfium headers for those definitions. Probably resolves to some compiler-specific directives.

Comment: @Shawn Oh I know the definitions here, e.g. #define FPDF_EXPORT, but I would like to learn what this is, is it just an additional return type or whats going on? What is it called?

Comment: Why don't you add the definitions of those macros to the question if you already found them?

Comment: @Gerhardh Becaus I'm inexperienced with C and usage of macros in this way. At first glance, this seemed to be some very C language specific thing, but if you don't know what to even call them, then search the web is quite hard. Me, thinking this is something common and well known, gave just the barebones of the code, and though someone would repond with a simple "Ah this is `x` with functions" or whatever. In hindsight its easy to see my question was poorly worded and didn't include enough code. Now hop off...

Comment: That was meant as a hint that you could add it to the question now. In general you should provide all related information. These macro names do not have any meaning unless you are using exactly that library. The replacement text is likely much more widely used and known.

Comment: @Gerhardh Good point, I'll add them. Didn't really think it was necessary when the question was already answered, but I'll add them shortly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I could not find the specific macros or the function you reference here: https://github.com/PDFium/PDFium

You should probably add what specific version of your library you are using.

However, there are things in C function declarations besides return type, function name, and parameters that come from outside C it self.

One specific one, which is not part of the C standard, is the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), which specifies how sending parameters and returning from function works.

Since the keywords to specify this convention are compiler specific, it makes sense to put them in a conditional macro, to make the code portable.

It may also be done to support cross-compilation for different hardware.

So `FPDF_CALLCONV` is most likely something like this:

```
#ifdef SOME_CONDITION_TO_USE_STD_CALL
    #define FPDF_CALLCONV __stdcall
#endif
```

Another non standard option in C (and C++) programs is a directive to [export a function when building a DLL on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-160).

Since this is platform specific, to make C code cross-platform, it also needs to be in a conditional macro.

So, `FPDF_EXPORT` is likely something like this:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #define FPDF_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define FPDF_EXPORT
#endif
```

Note, that on other platforms this kind of "marking" does not exist, so the macro can expand to nothing, leaving the function declaration in a more familiar form.

It should also be left blank in the version of h file you include to use the library as opposed to the one used to compile the library, as you don't need this prefix to call the function.

To conclude, it is likely you can omit these two macros in your Cuthon interface, assuming the library you are using is compatible with your platform.

Comment: Wow, thanks! So this is just something Windows specific that you probably won't see on POSIX? Thanks for the tip on Cython too :D

Comment: I think the most important practical point is that they're details that Cython doesn't need to know about.

Comment: @HåkonTønnessen yes, on Windows, linking to DLL has several additional steps compared to POSIX system. For example, on the exe side, you need a .def file for the EXE specifying which functions are exported. The .h is not enough. On POSIX, all you need is the header and the library binary.

Comment: @DavidW in the case of  `__stdcall`, the calling convention is part of the functor-types (i.e. you cannot convert `__cdecl` function to a `__stdcall`-functor). Thus Cython supports calling conventions: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#windows-calling-conventions

Comment: @ead Thanks, I didn't know that. I'd think that only really matters if you want to use function pointers (and not for call it as a regular function) but it's still useful to know

Comment: @DavidW no, calling convention has nothing to do with function pointers. It specifies where the parameters go (stack or registers) and who cleans the stack (the function or the code that called it). You can ignore it only if the library was built with the same calling convention as the code you want to call it. That is why I said "assuming the library you are using is compatible with your platform" - any OS has a default convention, so if the library and binary using it are built for same OS, convention will be the same automatically.

Comment: @LevM. that is true, but in Cython you don’t need to know the calling convention when wrapping a function, unless you take a function pointer of it or want to pass a cdef function as a functor with different calling convention.

Answer (score 1):

FPDF_EXPORT and FPDF_CALLCONV are Macros, they are defined in the file :
https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/master/public/fpdfview.h

They are needed here because the library is available for different systems, and different systems have different conventions for creating the library interface.

These calls are extensions to the format you are familiar with:

```
return_type function_name(args)
```

For example you can see that FPDF_CALLCONV dissapears unless you are building the library for windows.

Comment: Thanks! I know they are macros, but I if these evaluates to `define FPDF_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)`, then what would you call the `__declspec(dllimport)`? I mean the Microsoft documentation calls these keywords, but looking for C function keyword doesn't yeld much information... What are these usually called?

Comment: @HåkonTønnessen then why don't you ask this in the first place instead of what `FPDF_EXPORT` is?

Comment: @Gerhardh "Could someone breifly explain what they are or point me to some resources I could use?" ~= "What are these usually called?/What are they?" - Different ways of interpreting that, but I meant exactly that when I asked the question. Jesus Christ man, you really don't give people the benefit of doubt, do you? Hop off, mate